# Принцип работы figma. Как сделать мини аналог?

Tags: javascript, canvas, typescript, figma

Есть желание попрактиковаться и попробовать написать свою очень простую figma ( Добавление на канвас прямоугольников, изменение размеров, удаление приближение камеры и тд). Что посоветуете изучить.

Опыт работы в react, vue, nuxt - можно их к ответу прикрутить

Вопросы:

- Как реализовать приближение / удаление камеры

Answer (score 2):

### - ,-

> Что посоветуете изучить.

MDN - mozilla developer network

> Как реализовать приближение / удаление камеры

Figma использует `canvas`.

- `ctx.scale` [доки](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale)

### -, -

- https://developer.mozilla.org
- https://www.google.com/?q=%22typescript%22%20canvas%20library

---

### O_O

1. https://www.google.com/?q=figma%20tech%20stack
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/is7bxt/what_is_a_good_techframework_stack_to_create_a/

   > excalidraw is built with React and could be an inspiration for your project. You could take a look at how they did it: https://github.com/excalidraw/excalidraw
3. https://github.com/excalidraw/excalidraw